Logging messages sent from IOTHUB to DEVICE (C2D)
Is there a way possible where I can use an azure service which lets me log messages received by IOTHUB in C2D(Cloud to Device) way of communication.
Currently I am able to log messages using message routing in IOTHUB when using D2C (Device to Cloud) way of communication.
I was not able to find any method in IOTHUB which will let me log C2D (Cloud to Device) messages.
